# Drawing a Sierpinski Triangle in Racket

Tags: recursion, nested, racket

I am trying to do a nested pyramid in Drracket and I have hit a wall. I was hoping to get some help. I need nested pyramid to output (nested-pyramid (circle 10) 1) or (nested-pyramid (circle 10) 3) and have the pyramid change sizes.

```
(define (nested-pyramid p)
  (define pyramid p)
  (define p 1)
 (if (= p 1))
      pyramid p
(else (- p 1))
  nested-pyramid p)
```

The code I have for pyramid p is:

```
(define (pyramid p)
  (define two-p (hc-append p p))
  (vc-append p two-p ))
```

[image: instructions]

Comment: What's a nested pyramid, exactly?

Comment: After creating the pyramid our instructor wants us to be able to nest these pyramids to an arbitrary depth; that is, he wants us to be able to draw a pyramid of a pyramid of circles, or a pyramid of a pyramid of a pyramid of circles.

Comment: Sure, that's a fractal called a Sierpinski triangle. I wasn't sure what you were going for but the description helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create a nested pyramid from a shape *p* with depth *n*, assuming *n* is an integer greater than or equal to 1:

- if *n* is 1, create a pyramid from shape *p*;
- otherwise *n* must be more than 1, so create a nested pyramid from *p* with depth *n - 1*.

You create a pyramid from *p* with `(pyramid p)`.  However `pyramid` can be made quite a lot simpler than your definition:  if you have something that says

```
(define ...
  (define x ...)
  ... use x exactly once ...)
```

It is very often better to just use the form that created `x` rather than inventing a variable you use exactly once.  So

```
(define (pyramid p)
  (define two-p (hc-append p p))
  (vc-append p two-p))
```

can instead be

```
(define (pyramid p)
  (vc-append p (hc-append p p)))
```

Thinking about the difference between these two versions of `pyramid` might help write `nested-pyramid`.  If you are using something lots of times then creating a name for it can be both clearer and perhaps more efficient:

```
(define (rocket p)
  (define three (hc-append p p p))
  (vc-append p
             (hc-append p p)
             three
             three
             three
             three
             three))
```